# What is a lightweight mail client with facility for calender?

Tags: software-recommendation, lubuntu, mail, calendar

I need something that does repeat dates (like in outlook) so I can put my weekly schedule in and color code it. I have not found anything yet.

I used to use thunderbird for the mail side of things, but wasn't that keen. I am now using Sylpheed for mail, but it is a little too limited for what I want, so I am hoping there is something else about.

Running lubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe [Claws Mail](http://www.claws-mail.org/index.php) would would work for you? Sylpheed was forked from Claws a while ago but Claws is still around and has many plugins such as [vCalendar](http://www.claws-mail.org/plugin.php?plugin=vcalendar).
I also installed Claws to check it out and it's interface is very similar to Sylpheed and is also just as light (certainly much lighter than Tbird). It also auto-migrates your Sylpheed settings at install.

**Claws Mail**:

[image: Install via the software center]

**Sylpheed**:

[image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 3):

Well I use Thunderbird with the [Lightning](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/lightning/) add-on. It works great for me.

Comment: It works, well, worked for me... until the recent version 15 that is *slow as hell* and hangs for at least 10 seconds each launch.